# UINavigationController transparent for UITableView underneath

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

I have a UINavigationController handling then navigation in my app. I would like the navigation bar to show the contents of the UITableView as I scroll up.

I can't seem to get it to be transparent. I have it set to translucent

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
```

But still nothing. I'd like to add color, but I'll worry about that later. I've tried creating a subclass of UINavigationController and specify

```
self.navigationBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
```

But again, no luck. This is what my interface builder looks like...

[image]

And this is what it looks like when I scroll the text up under the nav bar. Any suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, I figured out a (seemingly simple) solution.

If you're using a UINavigationController to add a UINavigationBar to each of your views, this will work for making a transparent navigation bar.

Select the Navigation bar in your UINavigationController

[image]

Then, in the inspector bar (on the right), select "Clear Color". Tada! I'm a bit embarrassed I didn't try this sooner. Hopefully this will save someone else lots of time.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try using a UITableViewController embedded in a UINavigationController, instead of a UIViewController. It'll adjust the insets for the iOS7 live blur automatically, so that the list content will show up under the Toolbar/NavigationBar on scroll.

I can't really make it out from your screenshot, but you can disable 'Hide Toolbar' in the parent NavigationController. You then don't have to add it separatly.

Comment: As on, reconstruct the interface in IB? Or subclass in the .h? interface listViewController : UIViewController <-- change this to UINavigationController? Thanks! @mmackh

Comment: Reconstruction of the interface. Use a UITableViewController instead of a UIViewController. It's built into XCode, no need to subclass.

Comment: Rebuilt it today with a UITableViewController, same result. Any more ideas @mmackh?

Comment: Are you testing this on a device or on the simulator?

Comment: I was testing on both, see my solution. Thanks for your help!